# How to "Show & Hide Content with Toggle Button" for multiple divs?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create toggle button for multiple divs. I found one good tutorial, sharing the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.example2').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-example2" class="button">Open/Close</a>');
    $('a#toggle-example2').click(function() {
        $('.example2').slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

How do i change the code for multiple div classes, like .example2, .example3, ....

Here is the tutorial: http://rpardz.com/blog/show-hide-content-jquery-tutorial/

Comment: I am trying to create multiple tables which will have option toggle divs (show/hide). AND if js is disabled all tables will be visible. As shown in the tutorial (link above).

The tutorial is about showing hiding one div only but i want this for multiple divs

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried? [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the div classes then you can write the below code into a separate function as:

```
    function applytoggle(divclass) {
    var linkId = 'toggle-'+divclass; 
    $('.'+divclass).hide();
    $('.'+divclass).before('<a href="#" id="'+linkId+'" class="button">Open/Close</a>');
    $('a#toggle-' + divclass).live('click', function () {
        $('.'+divclass).slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
    });
}
```

then you can call register toggle events for all the divs as

applytoggle('example1');
applytoggle('example2');

EDIT: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QLGwr/6/

Comment: Will you elaborate please!!

Yes i know the div classes

Comment: I have taken out the code given by you into a function which accepts a  class name for a div. Then it applies the same logic as mentioned by you on the particular element.Since i have created as a function, it can be applied on 'n' number of div tags. i have used 'live' because anchor tag <a> is created dynamically !!!

Comment: If you think this is the solution, accept this answer as solution.